# Push images to AWS ECR through direct connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

Currently, I push my docker images from on-prem machines to AWS Private ECR through the Internet. I have a Direct Connect now and my question is can I push the images from on-prem VM to ECR through Direct Connect or VPN.

From the docs I read, It always uses the Internet to push images from on-prem.

Comment: ECR addresses use public DNS, and believe me when I say it you don't want to have those assigned via direct connect internal DNS. it's a major PITA.

Comment: Because of some standards, I have to push the images internally and I'm thinking about proxy or internal DNS, as your comment I will try with proxy first.

Answer (score 0):

There might not be any direct way to do this. However, A possible solution is using VPC Endpoints to ECR in the Direct Connect Linked VPC.

You can create VPC Endpoint for ECR in a VPC which uses private routing inside AWS for Communication instead of the public internet. Reference- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html

It should be then be possible to interact with the VPC Endpoint while going through Direct Connect. As reaching Internal Address' is possible via the Same.

Comment: I read this docs and I think VPC Endpoints cannot solve my case directly. I guess a proxy or internal DNS can help, need to do some tests.

Comment: @FranxiHidro, Did you figure this out? Did this solution work?

Comment: I don't test it but I believe I won't work. For example, if you use vpc endpoint and ecr is using public domain, how can a VM in on-prem network use vpc endpoint to translate the ecr domain? Your idea will work in case of using vpc peering or tgw on AWS only.

Comment: Any updates on this? I am looking to push from on-prem to a private ECR and I'm pretty sure it would work via the dkr.ecr VPC endpoints. This works when accessing S3 via the VPC endpoints.

Comment: @Morariu, Can you test it out? I dont have an on-prem setup anymore. It'll be great if you could let me know over here if it works or not.

Comment: @KashishSoni I am currently facing issues with docker login from the on-prem machine. Specifically getting this "Error response from daemon: Get "https://123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v2/" when running the "aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/"